# Converting Java to a usable Googlesheets formula or appscript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to streamline a task at work as currently the tool we use only accepts 1 6 digit number and then it generates a "check digit" which is the 7th number in the string.
The problem is when dealing with large amounts of inputs this is a time consuming task.

I've attempted using the standard check digit tools on google sheets but to no avail.

Here is the code from the current tool we use.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to Java unfortunatly

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="/gin/StyleSheets/GinGeneral.css" />
<TITLE> Calculate Check Digit</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="Javascript1.3">

var clearField = false;

function checkKey(){
if (clearField){
document.form1.elements(0).value = "";
document.form2.elements(0).value = "";
clearField = false;
}
}

function checkKeyPressed(){
if (window.event.keyCode == 13){
action();
}
}

function action(){
var strLine = document.form1.elements(0).value;
if(strLine == null){
  return false;
}
if(strLine.length !== 6){
 alert ("You must enter a six-digit line number");
 window.event.returnValue=false;
 return false;
}
if (isNaN(strLine)){
 alert ("You must enter a six-digit line number");
 window.event.returnValue=false;
  return false;
}
//Split string into five elements and multiply by required number 1-2-1-2-1-2 is the order used
var dstr = 0;
var d1 = strLine.substring(0,1) * 1 ;
var d2 = strLine.substring(1,2) * 2;
var d3 = strLine.substring(2,3) * 1;
var d4 = strLine.substring(3,4) * 2;
var d5 = strLine.substring(4,5) * 1;
var d6 = strLine.substring(5,6) * 2;
var sumval = 0;
var finalval = 0; 
var dT = 0;
//alert ("digit 1= " + d1 + "\ndigit 2 = " + d2 + "\ndigit 3 = " + d3+ "\ndigit 4 = " + d4+ "\ndigit 5 = " + d5 + "\ndigit 6 = " + d6);
//        'Add each element together, but if valx is more than one char, add each element together (assumes
//  'value will never be more than two digits as 2*9 = 18.

//Digit1
dstr = d1 + "";          //convert to a string so that you can read its length
if (dstr.length == 1){
  sumval = (d1 - 0) ;
} else if (dstr.length == 2){              //if the length is 2, add the digits together
  dT = (dstr.substring(0,1) - 0) + (dstr.substring(1,2) - 0);
  sumval = (dT - 0);
}
//Digit2
dstr = d2 + "";          //convert to a string so that you can read its length
if (dstr.length == 1){
  sumval = sumval + (d2 - 0) ;
} else if (dstr.length == 2){              //if the length is 2, add the digits together
  dT = (dstr.substring(0,1) - 0) + (dstr.substring(1,2) - 0);
  sumval = sumval + (dT - 0);
}
//Digit3
dstr = d3 + "";          //convert to a string so that you can read its length
if (dstr.length == 1){
  sumval = sumval + (d3 - 0) ;
} else if (dstr.length == 2){              //if the length is 2, add the digits together
  dT = (dstr.substring(0,1) - 0) + (dstr.substring(1,2) - 0);
  sumval = sumval + (dT - 0);
}
//Digit4
dstr = d4 + "";          //convert to a string so that you can read its length
if (dstr.length == 1){
  sumval = sumval + (d4 - 0) ;
} else if (dstr.length == 2){              //if the length is 2, add the digits together
  dT = (dstr.substring(0,1) - 0) + (dstr.substring(1,2) - 0);
  sumval = sumval + (dT - 0);
  }
//Digit 5
dstr = d5 + "";          //convert to a string so that you can read its length
if (dstr.length == 1){  
  sumval = sumval + (d5 - 0) ;
} else if (dstr.length == 2){              //if the length is 2, add the digits together
  dT = (dstr.substring(0,1) - 0) + (dstr.substring(1,2) - 0);
  sumval = sumval + (dT - 0); 
}
//Digit 6
dstr = d6 + "";          //convert to a string so that you can read its length
if (dstr.length == 1){  
  sumval = sumval + (d6 - 0) ;
} else if (dstr.length == 2){              //if the length is 2, add the digits together
  dT = (dstr.substring(0,1) - 0) + (dstr.substring(1,2) - 0);
  sumval = sumval + (dT - 0); 
}
if( sumval < 11 ){ 
        finalval = 10-sumval;
} else if (sumval < 21){
        finalval = 20-sumval;
}else if (sumval < 31){
        finalval = 30-sumval;
}else if (sumval < 41){
        finalval = 40-sumval;
}else if (sumval  < 51){
        finalval = 50-sumval;
}else if (sumval  < 61){
        finalval = 60-sumval;
}
document.form2.elements(0).value = finalval;
window.document.form1[0].focus();
clearField = true;
window.event.returnValue=false;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY class="opaque" onLoad=window.document.form1[0].focus(); onKeyPress="checkKeyPressed();">
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD align="left" width="110x"><b> Line Number </b></TD>
<TD align="right">
<FORM name="form1" >
<INPUT id="line" type="text" size="6" onKeyPress="checkKey();" name="line" maxlength="6" onFocus=window.document.form1[0].select(); /></FORM></TD>
<TD align="right">
<FORM name="form2" >
<INPUT id="checkdig" type="text" size="1" name="Checkdig" maxlength="1" onFocus=window.document.form1[0].focus(); /></FORM></TD>
</TABLE>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD align=center width="110px" id="Search" class="CheckDigitBox" onClick="action();">Calculate</TD>
<TD align=center width="110px" id="Exit" class="CheckDigitBox" onClick="window.close();">Exit</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I've already tried breaking this down into sheets formulas but have failed at my attepts